# Update div's value, using ajax call

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a rating system in my app, and a `<div>` element with average rating in it. I need to update the average rating value, when I click on a star(it creates a new `rating` in a db). This is my view for index page, where I use rating:

```
<h1>List of casinos</h1>

<div class="casinos-list">
  <% @casinos.each do |casino| %>
    <div class="casino-item">
      <p class="casino-name"><%= link_to casino.name, casino %></p>
      <p class="casino-description"><%= casino.description %></p>
      <ul class="rating">
        <% form_id = "casino_#{casino.id}_rating" %>
        <%= form_for casino.ratings.build, html:
            { id: "casino_#{casino.id}_rating", class: 'star_rating_form' } do |f| %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :casino_id %>
          <%= f.hidden_field :score, id: "#{form_id}_stars", class: 'star-value' %>
        <% end %>

      </ul>
      <div id="<%= "average_rating_#{form_id}" %>" class="average-rating" data-rating="<%= casino.id %>"><span><%= casino.average_rating.to_f.round(2) %></span></div>
      <div id="<%= "rate_#{casino.id}" %>" class="rateit" data-rateit-mode="font">
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

and my `application.js`:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function () {

  $('.rateit-reset').remove();

  $('.rateit-hover').click(function () {
    var rating = $(this).parents().attr('aria-valuenow');
    var float_number = parseFloat(rating);
    var rating_form_input = $(this).parents().parents('.casino-item').children('.rating').children('.star_rating_form').children('.star-value');
    var form_id = $(this).parents().parents('.casino-item').children('.rating').children('.star_rating_form').attr('id');
    rating_form_input.val(float_number);

    $.ajax({
      type: 'post',
      url: $('#' + form_id).attr('action'),
      data: $('#' + form_id).serialize()
    })
  })

});
```

I tried to do something like this: `$(this).parents().parents().parents('.casino-item').children('.average-rating').children('span').load(location.href + ' .average-rating');`, but it created a new element near existing one. As I understand, I need to make one more `ajax` call. I tried to do it like this:

```
function updateRating () {
  var $target = $('.average-rating');
  $.ajax({
      url: '/casinos/',
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'get',
      success: function(data) {
        $target.html(data['response'])
      }
    }
  );
}
```

but it gives me all my casinos. I'm confused, how does `url` should look like in an `ajax` call? Or maybe I'm missing something else? Thanks in advance.

Comment: for starters: can't you just name/give id to your `<div>`? Then you will not have to navigate to it with all that `parent` stuff

Comment: It has an id: `id="<%= "average_rating_#{form_id}" %>"`

Comment: @url: you need to specify the correct action in your controller. Right now you are calling the `index` action of your `casinos` controller